# Quotient group always free over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: modules, free-modules

Im reading in some notes, that for any abelian group $G$ the quotient group $G/mG$ of $G$ is always free over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.
Isn't this false in general.
We can take $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $m=4$. Then $G/mG$ is 
$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and not free over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, what you are missing is that not everything that's written down is true :-)

Comment: Presumably they mean to take $m$ prime...?

Comment: Good to know :) There is also stated that the torsion group $G[m]$ is always isomorphic to $G/mG$, which is also false. I guess they mean finite abelian groups, but this is nowhere stated. Is there any way to save the above argument?

Comment: nope, $m$ should be an positive natural number. I guess its just an false statement..strange

Comment: What does $G/mG$ even mean, when $m$ is an integer and $G$ an arbitrary abelian group?

Comment: @Arnaud: it means the quotient of $G$ by the subgroup $mG = \{ mg : g \in G \}$. Equivalently, the tensor product $G \otimes \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, it makes perfect sense. I hadn't seen that before!